# Fetch fail with ERROR : POST 415 & GET 405

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-web-api, token

I tried to modify this Microsoft.docs Sample => [Call an ASP.NET Core web API with JavaScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0)
I want to use fetch POST to send `username` and `password`,and my `AccountController` should return `Token`
Before doing this , I already tested my `login` API on POSTMAN & Swagger, it works!
**UPDATE**
**I resolve the POST ERROR 415, but still have GET ERROR 405,can somebody tell me the reason? Thanks!**

My Error :
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TgAq.jpg)
My Testing:

```
{
  "username": "Genevieve",
  "password": "sss"
}
```

```
Curl

curl -X POST "https://localhost:5001/login" -H  "accept: text/plain" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"username\":\"Genevieve\",\"password\":\"string\"}"
Request URL https://localhost:5001/login

Server response
Code    Details
200 
Response body
Download
{
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJHZW5ldmlldmUiLCJqdGkiOiJmYjJhNjdlNC1hZWFjLTRkMTktOWU2ZC03NDk0ZTVmMWYwNzciLCJyb2xlcyI6IkFkbWluIiwibmJmIjoxNjI4ODM0NTcwLCJleHAiOjE2Mjg4MzgxNzAsImlhdCI6MTYyODgzNDU3MCwiaXNzIjoiYXBpMSJ9.8HqCMwAbm3KXMXTGo868dARfF1UfMC1BEniq01UfyFQ"
}
Response headers
 content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
 date: Fri13 Aug 2021 06:02:49 GMT 
 server: Kestrel
```

My Javascript Code :

```
function sendtoken(){
    const token_name = document.getElementById('token_name');
    const data = {
        username : 'Genevieve',
        password : 'sss'
    };
    fetch('login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept' : 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body : JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(() => {
        getToken();
    })
    .catch( error => console.error('Unable to send Token.', error));
}

function getToken(){
    fetch('login')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then( data => _displayToken(data))
    .catch( error => console.error('Unable to get Token.', error));
}

function _displayToken(data){
    const final = document.getElementById('Token');
    final.innerHTML = data.token ;
    console.log(data.token);
}
```

My API :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using api1.Helpers;
using api1.Models;
using api1.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;

namespace api1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly JwtHelpers helpers;

        public AccountController(JwtHelpers helpers)
        {
            this.helpers = helpers;
        }
        [EnableCors("GetPolicy")]
        [HttpPost("login")]
        public ActionResult<LoginResult> Login(Login model)
        {
            if (CheckPassword(model.Username,model.Password))
            {
                return new LoginResult(){
                    Token = helpers.GenerateToken(model.Username,"Admin",60)
                };
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }

        private bool CheckPassword(string username, string password)
        {
            if(username == "Genevieve")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fetch('login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept' : 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'applicaiotn/json'
    },
    body : JSON.stringify(data)
```

As you can see in your code, you wrote 'applicaiotn/json', which is not spelled right. It makes sense you got a 415 (unsupported media) because 'applicaiotn/json' is not supported.
Fix your spelling errors.

The `405`(Method not allowed) is because you don't have an endpoint at '/login' that supports `HTTP GET`(a method type).  You need to add another method/endpoint that has `[HttpGet("login")]` on it.

This is what you are looking for I think

```
    fetch('login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept' : 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body : JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(response => response.json()
        .then( data => _displayToken(data)
      .catch( error => console.error('Unable to get Token.', error))))
   .catch( error => console.error('Unable to send Token.', error));
```

Comment: oh,I fix it, thanks you. But, I still have ERROR 405, can you tell me reason? thanks

Comment: I got your point. Here is the question, my POST method will return this {"token":"????"}. How can I fetch it without add GET method? Thanks! I am trying your ans,wait a minute~

Comment: Thank you,@Alex,I finally see my token on the index.html